# Efficient multi-threaded write access to sparse array?

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading

I have a large array `double*`, and multiple threads write to it.

I protect each write with a `boost::mutex`, but that introduces contention and makes everything very slow, almost non-parallel.

Is there a better way to control multi-threaded write access to my array?

Specifically, how can I exploit that, in my case, the array is sparse, and each thread typically writes to different parts of the array; concurrent writing to the same index should be rare and happen mostly to a handful of array indices.

Edit: To be precise, each thread increases the value using `+=` on multiple array indices.

Comment: Are writes mostly segmented (ie, threads write to data far apart?)  Is spinning acceptable upon contention (ie, is it really really rare, and is priority inversion not a problem?)  Is memory overhead larger than the array itself acceptable, or something to be avoided even if it adds costs elsewhere?  Do you have C++11 support?  If not what is your threaded memory model?

Comment: Does access to the array occur continuously, or are there periods where it is guaranteed not to be accessed?

Comment: Are the manipulated indexes adjacent?

Comment: A `double*` is not an array. It is a pointer.

Comment: As a side note, if that `double` array is truly sparse, implementing it as an array is really inefficient. You might want to consider using a `map` instead.

Comment: Thanks, everyone! I am interfacing with a function that needs a `double*`, so it seems I cannot change it to use a map or `std::atomic<double>`. A message queue is a good idea, I'll go with boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/lockfree/examples.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a message queue. Make the enqueue method update atomically (i.e. a single pointer swap) and you should be able to recover your concurrency. Then have a separate (single) thread read from the queue and write to the array.

I can expand on this given a little more info on precisely what kind of updates are being performed. But in general, you can find many lock-free queue implementations that should help you do this (e.g. [here](http://moodycamel.com/blog/2013/a-fast-lock-free-queue-for-c++)).

Edit to answer OPs edit: You'll want to construct a class that stores the list of pairs of indices and the update values (or update functions).

```
class UpdateMessage {
    public:
    vector<Pair<int, int>> updates;   
}
```

Or something like it. The reader can then grab an update message and iterate over that vector performing all the updates for a given message.

---

### Using the MoodyCamel Queue

Assuming updates can be computed without locking the array, here's a fast and dirty implementation that should satisfy your requirements.

```
using namespace moodycamel;

typedef Updates vector<Pair<int, double>>;

ReaderWriterQueue<Updates> queue(100);
double array[] = initialize_array();
int sleep_interval = 10; // in microseconds, you'll probably want to do something smarter than a
                         // fixed interval here.

void read(ReaderWriterQueue queue) {
    Updates updates;
    bool succeeded = queue.try_dequeue(updates);
    if(succeeded) {
        for(auto it = updates.begin(); it != updates.end(); it = updates.next()) {
            array[it.x] = it.y;
        }
    }
}

void write(ReaderWriterQueue queue, Updates ups) {
    bool succeeded;
    do {
        succeeded = queue.try_enqueue(ups);
        usleep(sleep_interval);
    } while(!succeeded);
}
```

Of course, this spins the writing thread if the insertion fails. If that's not acceptable, you can simply use `try_enqueue` directly and do whatever you'd like to do in the case that the `enqueue` fails.

Comment: If there is another thread that simultaneously *reads* values from the array it also needs to be synchronized, to avoid simultaneous reads and writes to the same memory location, right?

Comment: The reads would have to be change the values in the array for that to be true. As it stands, the standard way to read from the array is to dequeue an element which is guaranteed to be an atomic operation.

Comment: Not sure I understand your answer. If I have another thread that reads the `array[34]` value, for example, (without modifying it) it must make sure that the writing thread is not simultaneously writing to `array[34]`, right?

Comment: Using a lockless queue like this stops you from that kind of read/write pattern. You can't write to array[34] because the only way to write is to enqueue a new value, which puts it on the end of the queue. The only way to read is to dequeue a value. As long as you stick to that API, the lockless guarantees are preserved.

Answer (score 3):

If your environment supports C++11, then just replace your double array with either

- `std::array<std::atomic<double>, N>` for fixed arrays, or
- `std::vector<std::atomic<double>>` for dynamic arrays.

As long as the different threads do not write to adjacent indices (i.e. false sharing of cache lines), the performance and scalability should be significantly better than it is with `boost::mutex`.

Answer (score 2):

If there is some granularity between access events (i.e. data writes are not occurring  continuously, and faster than execution flow can accommodate) to this single `struct`, then ***creating a thread safe producer consumer queue in C++ without using locks*** would be a viable option.   This approach would allow for data build up within the data queue during a period of high hit frequency, then, as hit frequency wanes, the queue would diminish in size as data is written out to the target (`struct`).  The end effect would allow you to regain execution concurrency.

The best description of an implementation (without reproducing it here) is here: ***[Creating a thread safe producer consumer queue in C++ without using locks](https://msmvps.com/blogs/vandooren/archive/2007/01/05/creating-a-thread-safe-producer-consumer-queue-in-c-without-using-locks.aspx)***.